# Looking for an accessibly captcha (with audio support) for my GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, accessibility, captcha

To protect my GWT application against bots im using SimpleCaptcha 
but the problem is that framework does not recognize people with disabilities.
So I'm looking for an accessible captcha framework  with Audio Support. Did you know any framework that can  integrate With GWT application?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recaptia.net. I haven't tried the plugin out but GWT integration can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-recaptcha/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the problems with this approach before deciding on a method [The Failure of Noise-Based Non-Continuous Audio Captchas](http://cdn.ly.tl/publications/decaptcha-audio.pdf)